# Future Predictions LSTM

Tags: python, future, lstm, forecasting, recurrent-neural-network

I have a data set of 1400 length.

I made every operation and trained an `LSTM` model using `Keras` on Python in an attempt to predict future points. My trained model learns well.

After compiling the model, I added a new random test set. My intent is to predict unseen future, for example 15 days, that are not included in trained data. When I add some test data with a constant value, my predictions become constant.

But when I add real values that I try to predict, my model fits well on this test data.

- So How can I handle it?
- Why does the model prediction change due to test data ?
- How can I predict the next 15 days that are not included in my training set ?
- How can I predict the unseen future?
- If LSTM models work only on known train and test sets why should I use it?

Comment: What kind of dataset are you working on?

Comment: Time series dataset.historical data.there are no worries on using it or training model.My question is how can I predict unseen future using LSTM ?

Comment: I also have the same issue about how to print out unseen time of value after  I used LSTM to train ,valid and test data.

Comment: Any progress in this?. I also have same problem